How to install Qt6 LinguistTools development package on Ubuntu 24.04?
My CMake compile error:
  Failed to find required Qt component "LinguistTools".

  Expected Config file at
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6LinguistTools/Qt6LinguistToolsConfig.cmake"
  does NOT exist


I've installed linguist-qt6 but that didn't make the error go away.

The file appears to be provided by the qt6-tools-dev package - see also How do I find the package that provides a file?

@steeldriver thanks, could you format it as an answer?
